# Need to generate a list based on one item name and number of items

Tags: list, ansible

I have two variables:

```yaml
name: "abc232323defg10"
cycle: "4"
```

I need to generate a list:

```yaml
list:
  - abc232323defg10
  - abc232323defg9
  - abc232323defg8
  - abc232323defg7
```

where:

```
abc232323defg9 = abc232323defg(10-(cycle-3)),
abc232323defg8 = abc232323defg(10-(cycle-2)), 
abc232323defg7 = abc232323defg(10-(cycle-1))
```

The variable "cycle" is the same as the number of items in the list, and I already have item where last 2 characters are the "largest number" (that is number 10 in the example). So other items should have last two characters subtracted from this "largest number" (with increments for each cycle). Cycle is never bigger then "largest number", but can be equal.
Order in the list is not relevant.

PS last two characters can be any number or even combination of one letter (a-z,A-Z) and one number. So it can be t1, or e9, or 88... that is why I think I need regex.

Any idea?

Comment: sorry, last two characters can be any number or even combination of one letter (a-z,A-Z) and one number. So it can be t1, or e9, or 88... that is why I think I need regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the variables

```yaml
  _name: "abc232323defg10"
  cycle: "4"
```

Declare the variables *prefix* and *index* by splitting *_name*

```yaml
  prefix: "{{ _name|regex_replace('^(.+?)(\\d+)$', '\\1') }}"
  index: "{{ _name|regex_replace('^(.+?)(\\d+)$', '\\2') }}"
```

give

```yaml
  prefix: abc232323defg
  index: 10
```

Declare the list *indexes*

```yaml
 indexes: "{{ query('sequence', params) }}"
 params: "start={{ index|int }} end={{ index|int - cycle|int + 1 }} stride=-1"
```

give

```yaml
  indexes: ['10', '9', '8', '7']
```

Finally, create product of the *prefix* and *indexes*, and *join* them

```yaml
  names: "{{ [prefix]|product(indexes)|map('join')|list }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  names:
    - abc232323defg10
    - abc232323defg9
    - abc232323defg8
    - abc232323defg7
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    _name: "abc232323defg10"
    cycle: "4"

    prefix: "{{ _name|regex_replace('^(.+?)(\\d+)$', '\\1') }}"
    index: "{{ _name|regex_replace('^(.+?)(\\d+)$', '\\2') }}"
    indexes: "{{ query('sequence', params) }}"
    params: "start={{ index|int }} end={{ index|int - cycle|int + 1 }} stride=-1"
    names: "{{ [prefix]|product(indexes)|map('join')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          prefix: {{ prefix }}
          index: {{ index }}
          indexes: {{ indexes }}
          names:
            {{ names|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
```